# What is the equivalent of a meta description for a PDF file to get a snippet in the search results?

Tags: google, google-search, search-results, pdf

What PDF metadata does Google take as description into SERP snippet?

Is it always the subject or has somebody experienced something else like author, keywords, or first text paragraph?